# Writing an alternate objective function for a given model formulation

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Solve the following linear program using the graphical method, Then write an alternate objective function for this model formulation such that the corner points (6,5) and (4,6) would be alternate optimal solutions.

Maximize Z = 3x<sub>1</sub> + 2x<sub>2</sub>

Subject to:

-3x<sub>1</sub> + 4x<sub>2</sub> <= 12

2x<sub>1</sub> + 4x<sub>2</sub> <= 32

x<sub>1</sub> <= 6

x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub> >= 0

---

My approach was that I first draw the graph based from the 4 equations that the equation Z is subject to (constraints)

I end up with a triangular region with 3 points, calculated by taking the equations (constraints) each point is intersected by

A(4,6)

B(6,7.5)

C(6,5)

I am stuck on the part where I need to use the corner points to find alternate optimal solutions. What do I do?

Comment: Both points need to be on the same isoline, does that help?

Comment: no, can emphasize more please